# Timer on Location Manager

Tags: swift, timer, cllocationmanager

Is it possible to invoke `didUpdateLocations`inside the `Timer` ? I mean..

```
_timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(_:didUpdateLocations:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Is that going to work ? If yes then it is going to update location every 10 seconds ?

Comment: Do not get location based on time interval as this is not the bet way to do it and you will probably be consuming a lot of battery. It is best to monitor the movements(use coremotion framework) of the user like walking or driving and get location based on distance filter set it every 10 meters or more. When the user is on stationary status then make sure to pause your location updates or just set location manager's desired accuracy to 3 kilometers and distance filter to a higher value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't invoke didUpdateLocations. If you want frequent updates, your best choice is the Standard location service:

> The standard location service is most appropriate for apps that
>   deliver location-related information directly to the user but it may
>   be used by other types of apps too. To start the service, configure
>   the desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter properties of the location
>   manager and then call the requestLocation(), startUpdatingLocation(),
>   or allowDeferredLocationUpdates(untilTraveled:timeout:) method. Never
>   specify an accuracy value greater than what you need. Core Location
>   uses the accuracy value you specify to manage power better. A higher
>   degree of accuracy requires more precise hardware like GPS, which
>   consumes more power.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager

Answer (score 1):

Your callback selector has to have a different signature:

```
class MyClass {

    func startTimer() {
        _timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.timerCallBack(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    // ...

    func timerCallBack(timer: Timer) {
        // Here you go.
    }
}
```

(Maybe contain some syntax errors; currently don't have Xcode at hand)

Comment: Yeah, I get that it might call the function which do smith, but exactly what i want is user location after a period of time

Comment: You cannot do so. You could call `requestLocation` on the location manager, but this will trigger an _async_ call to your delegates `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` implementation. There is no _synced_ way to do so